# How to convert a source code text file (e.g. asp php js) to jpg with syntax highlight using command line / bash routine?

Tags: bash, syntax-highlighting

I need to create images of the first page of some source code text files, like asp or php or js files for example.
I usually accomplish this by typing a command like

```
enscript --no-header --pages=1 "${input_file}" -o - | ps2pdf - "${temp_pdf_file}"
convert -quality 100 -density 150x150 -append "${temp_pdf_file}"[0] "${output_file}"
trash "${temp_pdf_file}"
```

This works nice for my needs, but it obviously outputs an image "as is" with no "eye-candy" features.
I was wondering if there's a way to add syntax highlighting too.
This might come handy to speed up the creation of presentations of developed works for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pygments](http://pygments.org/docs/formatters/#formatter-classes) is a source highlighting library which has PNG, JPEG, GIF and BMP formatters. No intermediate steps:

```
pygmentize -o jquery.png jquery-1.7.1.js
```

Edit: adding source code *image* to the document means you are doing it wrong to begin with. I would suggest LaTeX, Markdown or similar for the whole document and source code document could be generated.

Another easy/lazy way would be to create an html document using pygmentize and copy-paste it to the document. Not professional, but better than raster image.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I successfully adopted pygmentize for my needs. To complete things: do you know how to convert only the first page using this command? I searched the documentation but I cannot find any option for that.

Comment: pygmentize does not have any notion of pages, if I understand correctly what you need. You will have to do it either through intermediate format, or in the document you are using pygmentize at.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it on my Mac:

- I open up the file with MacVIM. MacVIM supports syntax highlighting.
- I *print* the file to a PDF. This gives me a paged document with highlighted syntax.
- When I *print*, The program Preview opens up to display the file. I can *Export* it to a jpg, or whatever my hearts desire.

### I don't have a Mac

This works with Windows too.

- You have to get [VIM](http://www.vim.org) although [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org) may also work. Any *program editor* will support syntax highlighting and allow you to print out with the highlighted syntax. So, pick what you like.
- You have to get some sort of PDF producing print driver such as CutePDF.
- Converting it to a jpg. I think Adobe Acrobat may be able to export a PDF into a JPG, or maybe the print driver can print to a JPG instead of a PDF. Or, you can send it to a friend who has a Mac.